# Find a numeric sequence of a specific length in a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to be able to extract a sequence of exactly 8 digits from a given string. The sequence is not located in the same place from string to string, and may consist of any 8 digits.

Examples of strings to be extracted from:

```
"123 ABCDEF 12345678 GHIJKLMN"
"12345678 ABCD 1234 EFGHIJKL"
"123 4567 12345678"
```

In each of the strings above, I need just the `12345678`.

I've already tried matching the regular expression `/\d+/`, but if any number appears before the `12345678`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome @bgue. Your english reads fine to me :).
Does other regular expressions works? What happen if you use expression to find everything or exactly 12345678? Maybe you should post some code because from what you describe it should already be working.

Comment: @kroiz The answer /\d{8}/ worked like a charm.  The 12345678 is variable like 56110005 56850000 56150000 41199998

Comment: The answer you just selected is incorrect.

Comment: See my comment on the answer you selected. Next time, consider waiting longer (a couple of hours, perhaps). A quick selection may discourage other, possibly better (possibly correct) answers. Also, quick selections are , IMO discourteous to those still preparing answers.

Comment: Thanks for moving the greenie, but consider removing it from my answer as well, to encourage other answers. I can think of other ways it could be done, and you don't want to discourage other answers. Then select an answer later. When you have time, have a look at this [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with the following regex:

```
r = /
    (?<!\d) # negative lookbehind: cannot match a digit
    \d{8} # match 8 digits
    (?!\d) # negative lookahead: cannot match a digit
    /x

 "12345678 ABCD 1234 EFGHIJKL"[r]
   #=> "12345678"
 "x123456789 ABCD 1234 EFGHIJKL"[r]
   #=> nil
```

Comment: Or, in english: "Match eight (and only eigth) digits". So "123456789" will not match at all. Also, nice trick with the square brackets. Didn't know that, very handy!

Comment: @Manuel, in case it's not clear, the square brackets are the method [String#=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), which extracts elements from a string, depending on the argument; e.g., `"abcde"[2] #=> 'c'`, `"abcde"[1..2] #=> 'bc'`, `"abcde"[2,3] #=> 'cde'`, `"abcd"[/bc/] #=> 'bc'`.

Comment: Yeah I knew about them, but not that they take regular expressions as an argument

Answer (score 3):

Try specifying that you need exactly eight digits:

```
/(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)/
```

Edit: Add negative look-behind and negative look-ahead to only match exactly 8 digit sequences. Credit: @CarySwoveland.

Comment: "123456789" [/\d{8}/] #=> "12345678"

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yeah you are right. I should've used negative look ahead and negative look behind

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want in two steps:

```
def find8_1(string)
  index = string =~ /\d{8}/
  return index && !(string[index+8] =~ /\d/) ? string[index,8] : nil 
end

# Some examples
puts "Results with find8_1"
puts find8_1("123 ABCDEF 12345678 GHIJKLMN") # => "12345678" 
puts find8_1("12345678 ABCD 1234 EFGHIJKL")  # => "12345678" 
puts find8_1("123 4567 12345678")            # => "12345678" 
puts find8_1("123 4567 1234567")             # => nil 
puts find8_1("123456789")                    # => nil


def find8_2(string) 
  arr = string.scan(/\d+/) 
  return arr.find { |s| s.size == 8}
end

# Some examples
puts "Results with find8_2"
puts find8_2("123 ABCDEF 12345678 GHIJKLMN") # => "12345678" 
puts find8_2("12345678 ABCD 1234 EFGHIJKL")  # => "12345678" 
puts find8_2("123 4567 12345678")            # => "12345678" 
puts find8_2("123 4567 1234567")             # => nil 
puts find8_2("123456789")                    # => nil
```

**Note** for this  solution if you used `arr.select` instead of `arr.find` the method will return an array with all the substring of 8 digits present in the string.

Thanks to @CarySwoveland to help me to improve my answer.

Comment: It returned the starting position of the 8 character sequence right? It´s also interesting. Thank you

Comment: This is incorrect for the same reason @AlexPan's answer is wrong.

Comment: Downvote is mine, not for an incorrect answer, but for allowing your answer to stand when you know it's incorrect.

Comment: You are ruthless :) but you have reason. Honestly yesterday I had no time ti modify them. And in fact I try to understand yours answer, and I learned a lot with them, thanks.<br> I will modify my answer with a valid one I hope, let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Good recovery, but not quite right. `index` gives the location where the match begins, but you cannot return `substring` before confirming that `your_string[index+9]` is not a digit (if the match was at the end of `your_string`, `your_string[index+9] #=> nil`, so that's not a problem). But wait, what if `your_string = '123456789 12345678'`?. `/\d{8}/` will match `1...9` and then you will find that's not a match, but you need to keep going to match on `1..8`. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) What you can do is this: `arr = your_string.scan(/{\d}) #=> ['123456789', '12345678']`, then `arr.find { |s| <some code> }`. Figure out what `<some code>` is. (btw, you may prefer to write `your_string[index..index+8]` as `your_string[index, 8]`) Be sure to test. Let me know if you have difficulty. I've recinded my downvote, even though in some parts I've been called "The Hangin' Judge".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok I'm not sure to get it. I re-modified my first answer with `substring = your_string[index,8] if index` but not sure that fixed it. For your suggestion, first thing this `arr = your_string.scan(/{\d})` don't work in irb if I'm right it's `arr = your_string.scan(/\d+/)` after that I think about `arr.find { |s| s.size == 8}`. That's right ?

Comment: Yes! That's right. `/{\d}` was a typo (which you see I had fixed). `arr = your_string.scan(/\d+/)` is correct. You asked if `arr.find { |s| s.size == 8}` is correct. It is, but you should know that from testing. I suggest you revise you answer.  I would have it begin, "You can do what you want in two steps:". (Everything preceding is extraneous.) Show your code and show how it applies to a couple of examples; e.g., `def find8(str)...end` then `find8("123456789 01234567') #=> "01234567"`, `find8("123456789") #=> nil`, etc. You can use either `[index..index+8]` or `[index,8]`--your preference.

Comment: You might point out that if use `select`, rather than `find`, all strings of 8 digits will be returned in an array. I see I hadn't fixed all the `{/\d`'s. :-)

Comment: Done, I think now everything is correct, if not let me know :)

Comment: Two upvotes! You've a chance for at least one more. For `find8` #1, `find8("123456789")=> "12345678"`, which is of course wrong. Instead of `return index ? string[index,8] : nil` you need `(index && <some code>) ? string[index,8] : nil`. (Hint: review my comment ending "(cont.)".) `return` in the last line of both methods is not needed. That's because Ruby returns the return value from the last statement executed if there's no explicit `return`. (It does no harm, but shouts, "Hey, I'm a newbie!"). Lastly, surround `arr.select` and `arr.find` with backticks ( \` ) in your penultimate sentence.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ok should be fix now... lot of edge case I don't realize, thanks to point them. For the `return` I know that is optional in ruby but I like to use it, I found that is more clear a method become complicate. Ok maybe it is not a good reason, and maybe this show the need of some refactoring...

Comment: Excellent! I think you're finished. Note you can write: `string[index+8] !~ /\d/`